# Want tag for graphviz

Tags: feature-request, tags

It would be great if there were a tag for questions about graphviz within jupyter notebooks.  This would be applicable to the question [How to display graph with MathJax in jupyter notebook?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/57020).

Answer (score 2):

Before I start, I need to say that the [referenced question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/57020/29575), is a really great question.  I hope it gets some good answers.

And as to the inquiry about adding a new tag, thanks for bringing it to Meta.  But...

Let's ask ourselves [why do we tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31776/347908)?  If you follow that link, you will find (to my mind) that there are two primary benefits to tags.

1. For me, the most important point of tagging is to help me find questions to answer.
2. The second most important reason for tagging (in my opinion) is to help others find the information they may need.

I would argue that the referenced question, while a great question, is narrow enough, that tagging it as specifically as suggested, is unlikely to help it find an answer-er, or help those needing the answer find the answer via the tag.  And thus, the suggested tag is not likely to be super beneficial.